# How to find the web.config file in WCF application and what are the references are used in that file?

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm new to the WCF applications. how do you find the web.config file in wcf application and is there any specific folder to find those application. and how to trace a specific method by using enterprise logs in wcf applications.

Rgards
raghava

Comment: Please try to be more clear about what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You can trace specific method by opening the .svc file and searching in it. Web.config file can be found under the service folder.

if you have dlls of your service extract the assemblies with reflector and search for specific method.

Comment: is there any way to find  tracing and loging a specfic method in wcf app by using enterprise logs  can you pls help me